# Get JSON in a Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome

I would like to make a google chrome extension, however I have been rubbing my head on a problem all night.  I have the following code giving me a problem:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var resp;
xhr.open("GET", "http://www.roblox.com/catalog/json?Subcategory=16&SortType=3&ResultsPerPage=10", true);
xhr.onload = function () {
    resp = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
}
xhr.send();
```

I'm attempting to obtain some JSON data.  If I replace this section of code with `var resp = //(The actual JSON data itself)`, then the extension works just fine.

How can I fetch this JSON data correctly, and still have it compactable with anyone who downloads my extension?

Sorry if there's an obvious answer, I'm still new to Javascript.

Thanks!

Comment: `.onreadystatechange` instead of `.onload`, and check both xhr.readyState = 4 and xhr.status == 200 to check when you have a response. [MDN Example](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/XMLHttpRequest/Usar_XMLHttpRequest#Example.3A_Asynchronous_request)

Comment: Maybe try using JSONP...?  I'm not sure you can use it with Chrome Extensions, though.

Comment: It would be easier, IMO, to use jQuery or similar (which abstract this complexity away from you).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the content type. Not all browsers use the same default.

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "*/*");
```

Comment: This will help my compatibility issues.  During the insertion of this line, I also realized that one of my variables needed to be global.  Simple mistakes are often the hardest to find!